# how do I omit the grapical representation of some relationships with Neo4j browser?

Tags: neo4j

In the Neo4j 2.1.6 Browser, a query like this...

```
MATCH (a:A {name: "blah"})-[:SOME_REL]->(b)<-[:DOES]-(c) RETURN a,b,c
```

...also depicts a relationship that happens to exist among `b` nodes that I don't wish to show. How do I specify my query to selectively omit relationships?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the browser does a secondary request to pull the additional relationships.

Afaik in Neo4j 2.2.GA there will be an option to disable that behavior.